# <?php echo $_GET['keyword'];?> in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['keyword'];?>" placeholder="keyword" id="keyword" name="keyword" class="form-control">
```

was wondering whats the more elegant way to write this in Laravel 5?

```
<input type="text" value="{{php echo $_GET['keyword']}}" placeholder="keyword" id="keyword" name="keyword" class="form-control">
```

because I tried this but didnt work..

Comment: Explain your question clearly

Comment: @RajkumarR, i dont want to write value="<?php echo $_GET['keyword'];?>" because i think there should be a better way to write it in laravel for example: value="{{ ($get('keyword') }}"

Comment: but value="{{ ($get('keyword') }}"  seems to be a wrong syntax

Comment: check this format value="{{ $_GET['keyword'] }}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" value="{{$_GET['keyword']}}" placeholder="keyword" id="keyword" name="keyword" class="form-control">
```

OR

```
<input type="text" value="{{app('request')->input('keyword')}}" placeholder="keyword" id="keyword" name="keyword" class="form-control">
```

OR

```
<input type="text" value="{{Request::segment(3)}}" placeholder="keyword" id="keyword" name="keyword" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 1):

There are hell lot of errors in your code:

1. Check weather your file where you are writing the code have `.balde.php` extension, as `{{ }}` is only accessed through blade engine.
2. Your syntax for fetching the keywords is wrong `{{php echo $_GET['keyword']}}` blade engine doesn't require `php echo` .
3. You can fetch through database or request, for this you need to learn from [Database documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database) or [request documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests) respectively.

According to your question it should be:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ $_GET['keyword'] }}" placeholder="keyword" id="keyword" name="keyword" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
<input type="text" value="{{ $_GET['keyword'] }}" placeholder="keyword" id="keyword" name="keyword" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
<input type="text" value="{{ Request::get('keyword') }}" placeholder="keyword" id="keyword" name="keyword" class="form-control">
```

OR

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo Request::get('keyword'); ?>" placeholder="keyword" id="keyword" name="keyword" class="form-control">
```

By using this you will get benefit that in any case you will not get `keyword` parameter in url then it will return null. But if you will use `$_GET['keyword']` then this will gives an error if keyword is not in get request.